# Hadoop: Use only a part of the reduce Iterable

Tags: mapreduce

I have a situation in which I only want to use the first n values of the Iterable given to my reducer and then abort. I have been reading about the Iterable class and it seems like this may not be trivial.

I can't use a for loop or a next method. I can't use a foreach since it iterates over the whole object. Is there a straight-forward solution or am I approaching the problem wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just extract the iterator from the iterable and use a good old for loop, or a while loop.

For example, the below sums over only at most the first TOPN values.

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    private static final int TOPN = 10;

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum = 0;
        Iterator<IntWritable> iter = values.iterator();
        for (int i=0; iter.hasNext() && i < TOPN; i++) {
            sum += iter.next().get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the memory implications of taking an iterator from an iterable? Also, if I start again with iter.next(), am I correct to expect that the iterator will start throwing values from TOPN + 1 onwrads? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about any JVM-specific issues like memory implications, but my assumption is that the implementer of the Iterable interface is simply a wrapper for an actual iterator object inside, so you're just accessing a member object. The iterator will continue to update the object returned by iter.next() each time you call it until there are no more values. Warning: the same object reference is held/returned by iter.next() each time, only object's contents are changed. So remember to make a copy of the object if you need to hold on to it for more than one iteration.